# Why aren't string literals passed as references to arrays instead of opaque pointers?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14

In C++, the type of string literals is `const char [N]`, where `N`, as `std::size_t`, is the number of characters plus one (the zero-byte terminator). They reside in static storage and are available from program initialization to termination.

Often, functions taking a constant string doesn't need the interface of `std::basic_string` or would prefer to avoid dynamic allocation; they may just need, for instance, the string itself and its length. `std::basic_string`, particularly, has to offer a way to be constructed from the language's native string literals. Such functions offer a variant that takes a C-style string:

```
void function_that_takes_a_constant_string ( const char * /*const*/ s );

// Array-to-pointer decay happens, and takes away the string's length
function_that_takes_a_constant_string( "Hello, World!" );
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/2207421), arrays decay to pointers, but their dimensions are taken away. In the case of string literals, this means that their length, which was known at compile-time, is lost and must be recalculated *at runtime* by iterating through the pointed memory until a zero-byte is found. This is not optimal.

However, string literals, and, in general, arrays, may be passed as references using template parameter deduction to keep their size:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void function_that_takes_a_constant_string ( const char (& s)[N] );

// Transparent, and the string's length is kept
function_that_takes_a_constant_string( "Hello, World!" );
```

The template function could serve as a proxy to another function, the real one, which would take a pointer to the string and its length, so that code exposure was avoided and the length was kept.

```
// Calling the wrapped function directly would be cumbersome.
// This wrapper is transparent and preserves the string's length.
template<std::size_t N> inline auto
function_that_takes_a_constant_string
( const char (& s)[N] )
{
    // `s` decays to a pointer
    // `N-1` is the length of the string
    return function_that_takes_a_constant_string_private_impl( s , N-1 );
}

// Isn't everyone happy now?
function_that_takes_a_constant_string( "Hello, World!" );
```

Why isn't this used more broadly? In particular, why doesn't `std::basic_string` have a constructor with the proposed signature?

---

Note: I don't know how the proposed parameter is named; if you know how, please, suggest an edition to the question's title.

Comment: `std::string` having this as a parameter would introduce instances of `char arr[100]; fillFirst20Chars(arr); std::string s(arr);`.

Comment: @chris I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean that the `std::string` being created would be too long? If so, that could be mitigated with `std::string s(arr, 20);`.

Comment: I guess the issue is that implementors and users of `std:: string` assume that all the characters in the string are non-null and that the first character after the string is null. But this assumption would then be incorrect if some developers are careless. I guess this can be easily solved by deciding that the behaviour is undefined the assumptions about the placement of the `\0` are broken.

Comment: Look for `string_view` in the Library Fundamentals TS.

Comment: @Kalrish, Yes, you could, but a) Existing code does not, and b) It could very well be unexpected and undetected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's largely historical, in a sense. While you're correct that there's no real reason this can't be done (if you don't want to use your whole buffer, pass a length argument, right?) it's still true that if you have a character array it's *usually* a buffer not all of which you're using at any one time:

```
char buf[MAX_LEN];
```

Since this is *usually* how they're used, it seems needless or even *risky* to go to the trouble of adding a new `basic_string` constructor template for `const CharT (&)[N]`.

The whole thing is pretty borderline though.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with adding such a templated overload is simple:

It would be used whenever the function is called with a static buffer of `char`-type, even if the buffer is not *as a whole* a string, and you really wanted to pass only the initial string (**embedded zeroes are far less common than terminating zeroes**, and **using part of a buffer is very common**): Current code rarely contains explicit decay from array to pointer to first element, using a cast or function-call.

Demo-code [(On coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ad4f07ebbc912da):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

auto f(const char* s, size_t n) {
    printf("char* size_t %u\n", (unsigned)n);
    (void)s;
}
auto f(const char* s) {
    printf("char*\n");
    return f(s, strlen(s));
}
template<size_t N> inline auto
f( const char (& s)[N] ) {
    printf("char[&u]\n");
    return f(s, N-1);
}

int main() {
    char buffer[] = "Hello World";
    f(buffer);
    f(+buffer);
    buffer[5] = 0;
    f(buffer);
    f(+buffer);
}
```

Keep in mind: If you talk about a string in C, it always denotes a 0-terminated string, while in C++ it can also denote a `std::string`, which is counted.

Comment: While your point (that buffers are sometimes cut by inserting a zero-byte) is right, depending on buffers' contents to denote their size is offering yourself as a sacrifice for the gods of (stack) overflow. If you already know the size of the region you want to pass, why not explicitly state so?

Comment: Why do you think you know it? You passed a buffer to a function, which filled in a string, which you process further. Until the last step, you never knew the length of the string, only of the buffer. Also, I only set that 0-byte somewhere in the middle to demonstrate, it does not mean it was done that way at all.

Comment: Many functions return the number of bytes written (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf, for example), and even if they didn't, it would still be advisable to scan for the zero-byte: you know the size of the buffer, so you know when to stop, but a naive function you pass it to doesn't (it just receives a pointer), and may run out of bounds.

Comment: Well, you should know the called function's contract, naturally (and also take advantage of any ancillary information): So, does it guarantee 0-termination on success, or is it a crapshot?

Comment: I kept scratching my head over the syntax `+buffer`. The operator is called "unary plus", and may perform array-to-pointer decay, among other things. Search for "Unary arithmetic operators" in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is being addressed in C++14 building on user defined string literals

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //no need to write 'using namespace std::literals::string_literals'
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::string s2 = "abc\0\0def"; // forms the string "abc"
    std::string s1 = "abc\0\0def"s; // form the string "abc\0\0def"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper class that will fix that without using overload for every function

```
struct string_view
{
    const char* ptr;
    size_t size;
    template<size_t N>
    string_view(const char (&s)[N])
    {
        ptr = s;
        size = N;
    }
    string_view(const std::string& s)
    {
        ptr = s.data();
        size = s.size() + 1; // for '\0' at end
    }
};
void f(string_view);
main()
{
    string_view s { "Hello world!" };
    f("test");
}
```

You should expand this class for helper function (like `begine` and `end`) to simplify usage in your program.

Comment: This is a somewhat naive version of the `string_view` class that is being considered in the Library Fundamentals TS (thanks to Kerrek SB for pointing that out, it's just what I was asking for!).

Comment: @kalrish you can make this naive version a bit more generic as `array_view` as well (supporting `std::array`, `std::string` and `std::vector` input as well as raw C arrays).  Generally I give it a `begin` and `end` pointer rather than a `ptr` and `size` myself.